# NodeJS set / add cookies

Tags: node.js, cookies

I need simple Node JS server which returns some html page and set one or more cookies to it.

How should I add one or more cookies in Node JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you have directory and 2 files inside:

my_folder:

- main.js
- index.html

---

Steps:

1. Install cookie: **npm install cookie**
2. **main.js** should be next:

```js
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    cookie = require('cookie');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var setCookies = [];
    setCookies.push( cookie.serialize('name1', 'Jhon1') );
    setCookies.push( cookie.serialize('name2', 'Jhon2') );

    response.setHeader('Set-Cookie', setCookies);
    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

    fs.createReadStream('./index.html').pipe(response);
}).listen(8000);

console.log('Server is started: "http://localhost:8000"');
```

3. Run: $ node ./main.js